# Accessing the value of a zip object using its index

Tags: python

I am trying to understand how to access a zip object and I'm trying to figure out how to access the value in the zipped object using the index by using the .index() just as we have it before in Python 2.x but it seemed that it does not work in Python3

Here is the code

```
def find_neighbors(index):
    i, j = index
    print([(i + 1, j), (i - 1, j), (i, j + 1), (i, j - 1)])
    return [(i + 1, j), (i - 1, j), (i, j + 1), (i, j - 1)]

list1 = (211,209,210,210)
list2 = (72,72,73,71)
points = zip(list1,list2)

for i, index in enumerate(points):
    for x in find_neighbors(index):
          if x is not in points: continue
          j = points.index(x)
```

When I run the code, I am getting this error: AttributeError: 'zip' object has no attribute 'index'

Is there a new way on how to execute this same mechanism

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems like you expect `points` to be a list, but `zip` objects are not lists.

If you want to convert it to a list, then do this:

```
points = list(zip(list1,list2))
```

Comment: when I converted it, now Im getting ValueError: (211, 72) is not in list eventhough I have the value (211,72) on the zipped object.. ?? Any idea

Comment: Are you sure this is your real code?  It contains a syntax error `if x is not in`, but after fixing that I do not get the error you describe.

Answer (score 1):

`zip` used to return a list in Python 2 but is now a generator in Python 3, so you would have to convert it to a list using the `list` constructor first before you can use the `index` method:

```
points = list(zip(list1,list2))
```

Answer (score 0):

As the others say: zip returns a zip object which is an iterator you can use to make other things like a list or a dictionary. Also, (a,b,c) returns a tuple whereas [a,b,c] returns a list.

```
>>> type((1,2,3))
<class 'tuple'>
>>> type([1,2,3])
<class 'list'>
>>>
```

It may not matter to you unless you want to start modifying the contents of the "lists". You called them "lists" so I have made them lists below. In either case, once you zip them up and convert to a list (`list(zip(list1,list2)`), you get a list of tuples. In fact this makes your code a little easier because you can pass the tuple into your function:

```
def find_neighbors(point):
i = point[0]
j = point[1]
print(f"List of neighbours of {point}: {[(i + 1, j), (i - 1, j), (i, j + 1), (i, j - 1)]}")
return [(i + 1, j), (i - 1, j), (i, j + 1), (i, j - 1)]

list1 = [211,209,210,210,211]
list2 = [72,72,73,71,73]
pointsList = list(zip(list1,list2))

#These loops are just to show what is going on comment them out or delete them
for i in pointsList:
    print(i)
    print(f"The first element is {i[0]} and the second is {i[1]}")

#or let Python unpack the tuples - it depends what you want
for i, j in pointsList:
    print(i,j)

for point in pointsList:
print(f"In the loop for find_neighbours of: {point}")
for testPoint in find_neighbors(point):
    print(f"Testing {testPoint}")
    if testPoint not in pointsList:
        print(f"Point {testPoint} is not there.")
        continue
    elif testPoint in pointsList:
        print(f"*******************Point {testPoint} is there.***************************")
```

Notice that I have added a point to your data that is a neighbour so that we can see the function find it. Have a think about the difference between lists and tuples before you commit too much work to one route or the other. My code is written in Python 3.7.

Finally, remember that you could use a dictionary `pointDict = dict(zip(list1,list2))` which might be more use to you in your program especially if you need to look things up. It might be more pythonic.