# python: how do I zip up two arrays

Tags: python, numpy

I'm getting the following tuple, and trying to zip the values:

```
top_4 = (array([ 24, 126,  33, 106]), array([ 98, 135, 330, 339]))
```

how can I zip them together? I want [(24, 98), (126, 135), (33, 330), (106, 339)]

The tuple I'm showing for input is what my function is returning. I don't know how to get them out of that array wrapper, I guess.

When I do the following:

```
points = zip(max[0], max[1])
```

I get a 'zip' object that is not subscriptable.

Comment: You can just do `np.column_stack(top_4)`

Comment: `list(zip(*top_4))`

Comment: Possible duplicate: [Accessing the value of a zip object using its index](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55644043/accessing-the-value-of-a-zip-object-using-its-index)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Wrap your call to zip in list() and you should be able to script it.

Answer (score 3):

Your code will return a `zip` object which is meant to be iterated over, e.g. in a for-loop. Thus, if you want to unpack it, you must create a list from it:

```
points = list(zip(max[0], max[1]))
```

*Note: I'm assuming `max` and `top_4` in your code are interchangeable.*

Answer (score 0):

zip them one at a time. like this:

```
top_4 = ([ 24, 126,  33, 106], [ 98, 135, 330, 339])

m = [(top_4[0][i],top_4[1][i]) for i in range(len(top_4[0]))]
print(m)
```

output:

```
[(24, 98), (126, 135), (33, 330), (106, 339)]
```

Answer (score 0):

You can even use the star operator :

```py
points = list(zip(*top_4))
```

#### Performance comparison

```
%%timeit -n 1000000
list(zip(*top_4))
1.97 µs ± 63.9 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1000000 loops each)

%%timeit -n 1000000
[(top_4[0][i],top_4[1][i]) for i in range(len(top_4[0]))]
2.25 µs ± 142 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1000000 loops each)

%%timeit -n 1000000
[(x, y) for x,y in zip(top_4[0], top_4[1])]
2.46 µs ± 167 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1000000 loops each)
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
import numpy as np

top_4 = (np.array([ 24, 126,  33, 106]), np.array([ 98, 135, 330, 339]))

result = list(zip(top_4[0], top_4[1]))
print(result)
```

Output:

```
[(24, 98), (126, 135), (33, 330), (106, 339)]
```

Answer (score 0):

```
list_tuples = (([ 24, 126,  33, 106]),([ 98, 135, 330, 339]))


points = [(x, y) for x,y in zip(list_tuples[0], list_tuples[1])]


print(points)
```